# The hierarchy of the type AddEntryAction is inconsistent (Jface)

Tags: jface

i have the following class in eclipse

```
class AddEntryAction extends Action {
  public AddEntryAction() {
    super("Add Entry");
    setToolTipText("Add Entry");
  }
  public void run() {
    WizardDialog dlg = new WizardDialog(MainClass.mainWindow.getShell(),
        new AddEntryWizard());
    dlg.open();
  }
}
```

and Action class extends AbstractAction which intern extends EventManager class. Both these parent classes are part of the eclipse SWT/jface libraries... I get the following error on the above class declaration

> The project was not built since its
> build path is incomplete. Cannot find
> the class file for
> org.eclipse.core.commands.common.EventManager.
> Fix the build path then try building
> this
> project   DisplayExample      Unknown Java
> Problem
>
> The type
> org.eclipse.core.commands.common.EventManager
> cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
> referenced from required .class
> files MainClass.java  /DisplayExample/src line
> 94    Java Problem

AddEntryAction is declared within the same source file MainClass.java. Actually, this is an example from [Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/org.eclipse.jface.viewers/TableViewersetInputObjectinputs.htm) ... I have the libraries/jars because i can see the compiles classes of all these clases

Answer (score 3):

The error "The project was not built since ... org.eclipse.core.commands.common.EventManager cannot be resolved..." with swt/jface dependencies can be caused by missing reference sources or binaries containing org.eclipse.core packages in addition to org.eclipse.swt and org.eclipse.jface packages.

E.g. build path in my case included:
 swt.jar
 org.eclipse.jface_3.4.2.M20090107-0800.jar

Following jar was missing and caused above error:
 org.eclipse.core.commands_3.4.0.I20080509-2000.jar